# Are cobblers solely in the shoe profession?

Tags: terminology, redundancy

No pun intended.
A friend posted on social media looking for a "shoe cobbler". I realize cobbler is an antiquated term, but I wanted to know if it was necessary to specify 'shoe'?

> **[cobbler](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cobbler)**
>   <sub>OLD-FASHIONED</sub>
>   someone whose job is to repair shoes
>   (Macmillan Dictionary)

Comment: As a computer programmer I've seen a lot of cobbled-up code.

Comment: And of course a peach cobbler tries to fix desserts.

Comment: Presumably your friend wanted to forestall offers of recipes. Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of definitions of cobbler (not all) that include making of shoes _and_ other leather goods. Belts and suspenders? I haven't been able to find further elaboration. Definitely not horse gear which would be a 'saddler'.

Comment: Well, perhaps your friend needs his shoes fixed near a restaurant that serves [peach cobbler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobbler_(food)). _...(looks up and whistles aimlessly)..._

Answer (score 4):

[Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cobbler) has some interesting information on this:

> late 13c., cobelere "*one who mends shoes*," **of uncertain origin**. It and cobble (v.) "evidently go together etymologically" [OED], but the historical record presents some difficulties.

[Cobble](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cobble) is also of interest:

> "to mend clumsily," late 15c., **perhaps a back-formation from cobbler** (n.1), or from cob, via a notion of lumps.

Etymonline [defines 'cob'](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cob) as:

> a word or set of identical words with a wide range of meanings, many seeming to derive from notions of "heap, lump, rounded object," also "head" and its metaphoric extensions.

And [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cob) has 'heap, lump, rounded object'-like definitions for 'cob':

> - the central cylindrical woody part of the maize ear to which the grains are attached.
> - a round loaf of bread.
> - a hazelnut or filbert.
> - a roundish lump of coal.
> - a mixture of compressed clay and straw used, especially in former times, for building walls.

As you can see, the etymology is uncertain. It *could* be something to do with lumping things together, but your guess is as good as any.

'Cobbler' is primarily used for shoes, as [many](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cobbler) [definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cobbler) [point](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cobbler) [out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cobbler). (I can't find one otherwise, but that proves nothing)

**Ergo, I'd say it's safe to assume 'cobbler' is of or pertaining to shoes, *unless otherwise specified.***

Comment: +1 for the etymology. I do still think that a post heading **"Looking for a good cobbler"** without any qualification would elicit a lot more Apple Brown Betty, Blueberry Buckle Cake, and Cherry Crumble recipes than recommendations for shoe repair shops. (Yes, I know, there are [subtle differences](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65270/whats-the-difference-between-a-cobbler-crisp-crumble-buckle-and-betty) between the aforementioned and actual cobblers...or not-so-subtle differences, if you mean "shoe cobblers".)

Comment: Your 'OED' link links to ODO; OED is only available on subscription.

Comment: @Edwin you could say that to all my posts.. I'll bear it in mind

Answer (score 3):

Supplementing @marcellothearcane's answer, it appears that the term [**cobbler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobbler) could also refer to

1. “…a person who illegally forges passports and other documents” *The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* says it is American slang ([link](https://books.google.it/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA502&lpg=PA502&dq=cobbler%20forger&source=bl&ots=PFswsE5J3I&sig=rrGnBTMLAhBVQyuI4w9SvmY_Eck&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cobbler%20forger&f=false))
2. a species of [catfish](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/species/3311) commonly found in Australia
3. A shortening of any number of Australian fish whose name contains "cobbler": *Cobbler Wobbegong*, *Silver Cobbler*, *Estuary Cobbler*, *South Australian Cobbler*, *Cobbler Perch*, *Whitelip Catfish* ([Fishes of Australia](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/search?q=cobbler))
4. the name of a Scottish mountain, [*The Cobbler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cobbler)
5. a baked fruit dessert ([source](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=616&q=cobbler%20recipe&oq=cobbler%20recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.88709.92804.0.93237.11.11.0.0.0.0.141.1434.0j11.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.11.1431...0i22i30k1j0i67k1.vW4y6AhvhDQ))

Without any context, a person asking, “Where can I get a cobbler?” might receive any of the following answers: in an Australian fishmonger, in jail, in a baker's or supermarket, or in the high street. Of course, it goes without saying that the most common meaning of cobbler is a **shoe repairer**. But adding an extra word never does irreparable harm, and it is a common feature in any spoken language.

As can be seen below, Ngram lends some support for the redundant expression *a shoe cobbler*

[image]

Comment: Nice one. I overlooked the other meanings!

Comment: +1 One small dialect point—In my region, the fruit confection is by far the most common use of the word—I know what a (shoe) cobbler is, but my default term would be *shoe repair* (shop). I guess I would use cobbler for the profession, but I have much less occasion to discuss that than baked goods :).

Comment: @1006a maybe it's also an age thing, I wonder if Australians tend to associate "cobbler" with a fish. I am tempted to think that the dessert usually has a noun (peach, blackberry, apple etc.)  to qualify it, just saying "cobbler" is too vague.... or maybe not.

Comment: I think it's like "pie"—I would generally expect someone to specify the type, but it's certainly possible to just talk about the thing in the abstract. I don't know that age matters so much as region; I just asked my kids, and they all knew the term immediately (except the 17-month-old). Shoe making didn't occur to any of them. But I'm in a small town in the corn belt, where that kind of dessert shows up at every potluck, and cobbler is the most common form/term for it.